# pandas grouped weighted average with weights from records and values from column names

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, weighted-average

I want to compute a grouped weighted average where the weights are present as rows and the value to be averaged is present as the column name:

```
df_dict= {1: {0: 10, 1: 15, 2: 50, 3: 10, 4: 44},
 4: {0: 12, 1: 15, 2: 48, 3: 12, 4: 63},
 7.5: {0: 17, 1: 23, 2: 99, 3: 20, 4: 66},
 90: {0: 25, 1: 18, 2: 102, 3: 17, 4: 10},
 'grouping': {0: '38', 1: '38', 2: '38', 3: '86', 4: '48'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
display(df)

df.groupby(['grouping']).sum().reset_index()
```

gives:
[image]

But I am not sure how to compute the weighted average efficiently. Using numpy [Weighted average using numpy.average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241174/weighted-average-using-numpy-average) could be an option. But this would imply `df.apply` a custom function which is not well optimized.

Is there a better way?

### edit

I.e. is there a better way tan using:

```
df = df.groupby(['grouping']).sum().reset_index()
display(df)

def wavg(x):
    values = x.drop('grouping')
    values = values.reset_index()
    values.columns = ['value', 'weight']
    return np.average(list(values.value),
                      weights=list(values.weight))
df['wavg_location'] = df.apply(wavg, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reset_index() is not necessory here.

```
df_raw = df.groupby(['grouping']).sum()
```

And we can do the weighted sum without calling np.average()

```
df = df_raw.copy()
df['wavg_location'] = (df * df.columns).sum(axis=1) / df.sum(axis=1)
```

I timed two different approach in Jupyter notebook:

```
for i in range(100):
    df = df_raw.reset_index()
    df['wavg_location'] = df.apply(wavg, axis=1)
```

executed in 712 ms

```
for i in range(100):
    df = df_raw.copy()
    df['wavg_location'] = (df * df.columns).sum(axis=1) / df.sum(axis=1)
```

executed in 293ms